# Unity Swipe Inputs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I wrote a method for objectCreation at random places in the scene. I want this to happen in my game when a player Swipes the Screen. I am using the following code

```
void Start(){
    StartCoroutine (SwipeInput ());
}
void Update(){
if (Swiped) {
        if (Direction == Vector2.up) {
            RandomObjects ();
        } else if (Direction == Vector2.right) {
            RandomObjects ();
        } else if (Direction == -1 * Vector2.up) {
            RandomObjects ();
        } else if (Direction == -1 * Vector2.right) {
            RandomObjects ();
        }
    }
}
IEnumerator SwipeInput ()
{
     while(true){
        if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
            Touch t = Input.GetTouch (0);
            Swiped = false;
                    Vector2 initial = t.position;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);
            Direction = (t.position - initial).normalised;
            Swiped = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);
        } else {
            Swiped = false;
        }
    }

}
```

But the game is not working with while(true) in Coroutine. Thanks.

Comment: you are missing a yield in the else branch. otherwise update never returns

Comment: @Heisenburg But it is not recognising Swipes

Answer (score -1):

You should write "normaliZed" instead of "normaliSed"